# Pandas group by aggregate using division

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I'm wondering how to aggregate data within a grouped pandas dataframe by a function where I take into account the value stored in some column of the dataframe. This would be useful in operations where order of operations matters, such as division.

For example I have:

```
In [8]: df
Out[8]: 
  class cat  xer
0     a   1    2
1     b   1    4
2     c   1    9
3     a   2    6
4     b   2    8
5     c   2    3
```

I want to group by by class and for each `class` divide the `xer` value corresponding to `cat == 1` by that for `cat == 2`. In other words, the entries in the final output should be:

```
  class    div
0     a   0.33  (i.e. 2/6)
1     b    0.5  (i.e. 4/8)
2     c      3  (i.e. 9/3)
```

Is this possible to do using groupby? I can't quite figure out how to do it without manually iterating through each class and even so it's not clean or fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your `DataFrame`, you can use the following:

```
df.groupby('class').agg({'xer': lambda L: reduce(pd.np.divide, L)})
```

Which gives you:

```
            xer
class          
a      0.333333
b      0.500000
c      3.000000
```

This caters for > 2 per group (if needs be), but you might want to ensure your df is sorted by `cat` first to ensure they appear in the right order.

Comment: nice approach, however `reduce` would sum up the results of the divisions for > 2 per group. May or may not be what the OP wanted.

Comment: @miraculixx the sample data always appears to have two items per group, so it won't be a problem... but yeah... it depends if `reduce(pd.np.divide, [9, 3, 2])` should be an error or `1.5`.... that's why I mentioned *This caters for > 2 per group (if needs be)*

Comment: I like it, it's a direct answer to the question. I'm a little unclear on what happens with more than 2 categories, but it seems like it's extensible. The thing is, division in this case doesn't make a ton of sense in more than two categories.

Comment: @crackedegg if there should only be pairs, and it should be error if not (this will fail on just 1, but will work with 2 or more) then I suggest you to look hard at the other answers... I appreciate the accept but it may not really be what you're after depending what you want to achieve :)

Comment: There should never be less than 2, and usually there shouldn't be more than 2, so this is fine. I also chose this because it's more in line with how I was thinking in terms of grouping and reducing, it taught me a more general tool :). For this particular problem, in practice I'm likely to use @Andy Hayden's answer because it's a little more explicit in what's happening in this case. There's a chance this code will need to be used by someone else who is not super familiar with Pandas and personally I find it a little more readable in that situation.

Answer (score 3):

Without doing anything too clever:

```
In [11]: one = df[df["cat"] == 1].set_index("class")["xer"]

In [12]: two = df[df["cat"] == 2].set_index("class")["xer"]

In [13]: one / two
Out[13]:
class
a    0.333333
b    0.500000
c    3.000000
Name: xer, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I like this answer too, it's a little more readable, but does suffer from potentially not working for more than 2 categories without more manual work. On the other hand, totally works for my current application.

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach, step by step:

```
# get cat==1 and cat==2 merged by class
grouped = df[df.cat==1].merge(df[df.cat==2], on='class')
# calculate div
grouped['div'] = grouped.xer_x / grouped.xer_y
# return the final dataframe
grouped[['class', 'div']]
```

which yields:

```
  class       div
0     a  0.333333
1     b  0.500000
2     c  3.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to rearrange your data to make it easier to view:

```
df2 = df.set_index(['class', 'cat']).unstack()

>>> df2
       xer   
cat      1  2
class        
a        2  6
b        4  8
c        9  3
```

You can then do the following to get your desired result:

```
>>> df2.iloc[:,0].div(df2.iloc[:, 1])

class
a        0.333333
b        0.500000
c        3.000000
Name: (xer, 1), dtype: float64
```